# Add ComboBox to WPF DataGrid that pulls from a SQL DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF program that allows users to edit an SQL data table for part details given a part number. The user enters a part number and I use a table adapter to display their part number details to a data grid using a row filter. I want to be able to take a list of ObservableCollection and bind it to a certain column in my data grid (i.e have a select list drop down list of part types for the part type column). Here is my .cs:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            createDropDowns();
            context = new RefreshAppContext();            
            InitializeComponent();
            PartTypeComboBox.ItemsSource = partTypesList;
#if DEBUG
#endif
        }

        public void findButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var partNumber = inputBox.Text;
            // Searches for part number in db.
            var foundPart = context.RefreshPartTypes.Where(x => x.PartNumber == partNumber).ToList();
            if (!foundPart.Any() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Part not found. Please try another number.");
            }
            else
            {
                // Adapter used to fill DT with info from DB based on query(ies).
                adapter_PT.Fill(table_PT);
                DataView dv = table_PT.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = "PartNumber='" + partNumber + "'";

                // Fills data grid in UI.
                dg.DataContext = dv;
                PartTypeComboBox.ItemsSource = table_LV.DefaultView;
            }
        }
public void createDropDowns()
        {
            // Populate part styles from lookup table.
            partTypesList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            adapter_LV.Fill(table_LV);
            List<string> temp = table_LV.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[2].ToString()).ToList();
            foreach (var partType in temp)
            {
                partTypesList.Add(partType);
            }
            partTypesList.Add(""); // Add a blank option in case user needs to input blank cell.
        }
```

And here is my .xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="m_grid_AutoGeneratingColumn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,-145,-779,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="165" Width="1222" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" AlternationCount="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="PartTypeComboBox" 
                                        Header="PartTypeTest" 
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
                                        SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PartType}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I can get it to create a new ComboBox column with the correct list of information, but I cannot get that combobox to display (or bind?) onto my PartType Column populated from my table_PT data table. Direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="event_AutoGeneratingColumn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,-145,-134,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="165" Width="582" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" AlternationCount="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="comboCol" Header="PartTypeTest" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding partTypesList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding PartType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) which specifies the path to the display string property for each item.

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="PartStylesComboBox"  DisplayMemberPath="PartType "  Header="Test" SelectedValuePath="{Binding partStylesList}" />
```

Comment: With that edit I can no longer see the list of items I've attached onto the combo box. It just gives me an empty drop down box. Any more advice? Thanks!

Comment: @KaylaNinh is it displaying those values?

Comment: unfortunately no, it is not displaying any values

Comment: it should, if you can give team viewer or something , i can check

Comment: I unfortunately cannot. It only shows the correct combobox list when i set the DisplayMemberPath to "Key". My issue seems to be with connecting it onto a column on my datagrid. Instead of attaching onto the PartType column, it is making it's own column. Am I supposed to be setting SlectedValuePath, SelectedValueBinding, or SelectedItemBinding to my datagrid?

Comment: It should be selectedvaluepath

Comment: So I've got a combobox that displays the list correctly, I just cannot populate that column with the current data from the database. Here is my xaml, the combobox is in a DataTemplate inside a DataGridTemplateColumn.

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding partTypesList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding partTypesList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="PartType"/>

I've tried setting SelectedValuePath = "PartType" with no avail. I can't seem to connect the data from my PartType column of the DataGrid. Advice?